# AssertionFailedError. Как исправить ошибку?

Tags: java, junit

Столкнулся со следующей ошибкой при запуске теста метода findAll():

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: java.util.HashMap$Values@143640d5<[Employee{firstName='Ivan', lastName='Ivanov', salary='75000.0', department='4'}]> but was: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection@6295d394<[Employee{firstName='Ivan', lastName='Ivanov', salary='75000.0', department='4'}]>
    Expected :[Employee{firstName='Ivan', lastName='Ivanov', salary='75000.0', department='4'}]
    Actual   :[Employee{firstName='Ivan', lastName='Ivanov', salary='75000.0', department='4'}]
```

мотед finAll():

```
   @Override
public Collection<Employee> findAll() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(employees.values());
}
```

мой тест:

```
    @Test
void findAll() {
    HashMap<String, Employee> test = new HashMap<>();
    test.put("Ivan Ivanov", firstPersonDepartment4);
    employeeService.add(
            "ivAn", "ivAnOv", 75000, 4);
    assertEquals(test.values(), employeeService.findAll());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы ожидаете HashMap, а метод вам возвращает `java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableCollection` --> разные типы --> ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка связана с тем, что вы сравниваете разные типы коллекций: java.util.HashMap$Values и java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection. Чтобы исправить это, используйте метод assertEquals для поэлементного сравнения коллекций.

```
@Test
void findAll() {
    HashMap<String, Employee> test = new HashMap<>();
    test.put("Ivan Ivanov", firstPersonDepartment4);
    employeeService.add(
            "ivAn", "ivAnOv", 75000, 4);
    Collection<Employee> expected = test.values();
    Collection<Employee> actual = employeeService.findAll();
    assertEquals(expected.size(), actual.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < expected.size(); i++) {
        assertEquals(expected.toArray()[i], actual.toArray()[i]);
    }
}
```

Еще один варинат с вынесеными вызовами expected.toArray() и actual.toArray() до цикла

```
@Test
void findAll() {
    HashMap<String, Employee> test = new HashMap<>();
    test.put("Ivan Ivanov", firstPersonDepartment4);
    employeeService.add(
            "ivAn", "ivAnOv", 75000, 4);
    Collection<Employee> expected = test.values();
    Collection<Employee> actual = employeeService.findAll();
    assertEquals(expected.size(), actual.size());
    Object[] expectedArray = expected.toArray();
    Object[] actualArray = actual.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < expected.size(); i++) {
        assertEquals(expectedArray[i], actualArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше вынести вызовы expected.toArray() и actual.toArray() до цикла, а не выполнять на каждой итерации. И для наглядности в тесте лучше сравнивать сами массивы, а не отдельные элементы.

Comment: @insolor
добавил как еще 1 вариант